# Highcharts - Change value of text box when drilling down through chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Tricky one to explain this so please bear with me.

I have this Large Tree Map created with Highcharts:

http://jsfiddle.net/mb3hu1px/2/

```js
var data = {
    "ARS": {
      "01To03Years": {
        "N": {
          "ARGENTINA": 951433
        }
      },
      "Above05Years": {
        "N": {
          "ARGENTINA": 3719665
        }
      }
    },
    "CNY": {
      "03To05Years": {
        "N": {
          "CHINA": 162950484
        }
      }
    },
    "COP": {
      "Above05Years": {
        "N": {
          "COLOMBIA": 323390000
        }
      }
    },
    "EUR": {
      "01To03Years": {
        "Y": {
          "BELGIUM": 393292575
        }
      }
    }
  },
  points = [],
  currencyPoints,
  currencyVal,
  currencyI = 0,
  periodPoints,
  periodI,
  yesOrNoPoints,
  yesOrNoI,
  currency,
  period,
  yesOrNo,
  mil,
  causeMil,
  causeMilI,
  causeName = {
    'N': 'Country Name',
    'Y': 'Country Name'
  };

for (currency in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(currency)) {
    currencyVal = 0;
    currencyPoints = {
      id: 'id_' + currencyI,
      name: currency,
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[currencyI]
    };

    periodI = 0;

    for (period in data[currency]) {
      if (data[currency].hasOwnProperty(period)) {
        periodPoints = {
          id: currencyPoints.id + '_' + periodI,
          name: period,
          parent: currencyPoints.id
        };
        points.push(periodPoints);
        yesOrNoI = 0;

        for (yesOrNo in data[currency][period]) {
          if (data[currency][period].hasOwnProperty(yesOrNo)) {

            yesOrNoPoints = {
              id: periodPoints.id + '_' + yesOrNoI,
              name: yesOrNo,
              parent: periodPoints.id,
            };
            causeMilI = 0;

            for (mil in data[currency][period][yesOrNo]) {
              if (data[currency][period][yesOrNo].hasOwnProperty(mil)) {
              
                causeMil = {
                  id: yesOrNoPoints.id + '_' + causeMilI,
                  name: mil,
                  parent: yesOrNoPoints.id,
                  value: Math.round(+data[currency][period][yesOrNo][mil])
                };
                currencyVal += causeMil.value;
                points.push(causeMil);
                causeMilI = causeMilI + 1;
              }
            }

            points.push(yesOrNoPoints);
            yesOrNoI = yesOrNoI + 1;
          }
        }

        periodI = periodI + 1;
      }
    }

    currencyPoints.value = Math.round(currencyVal / periodI);
    points.push(currencyPoints);
    currencyI = currencyI + 1;
  }
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    animationLimit: 1000,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    levelIsConstant: false,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      borderWidth: 3
    }],
    data: points
  }],
  title: {
    text: ''
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

And as you can see there is also a text area underneath.

What I want is for every level that is clicked through on the chart, the text area updates with some random text.

So for example on the first drill down, the text area could literally just print out level 1, the second drill down print level 2 etc. etc.

If anyone needs anything else from my end please let me know.

Many thanks:)

Comment: I think that you should be able to use xAxis.setExtremes in case of treemap chart: http://jsfiddle.net/mb3hu1px/4/

Comment: This works great too - Thank you Grzegorz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this several ways. Here is how to do it with [`plotOptions.series.point.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click). What you need to do is capture the point click and render some text. As you do not describe what text to show this will just update the `textarea` with the clicked point's properties `name` and `value`.

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var thePointName = this.name,
                    thePointValue = this.value;
            $('#text').val(function(_, val) {
              return 'Category: ' + thePointName + ', value: ' + thePointValue;
            });
          }
        }
      },
      type: 'treemap',
      layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
      allowDrillToNode: true,
      animationLimit: 1000,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      levelIsConstant: false,
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        borderWidth: 3
      }],
      data: points
    }],
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  });
```

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mb3hu1px/3/).